# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when iterating through all the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

how to handle this exception "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"
my code : I create an array of 64 length then I intialized every index then I print the indexes to make sure I am fulling all  indexes but it prints up to  63 then gives the exception !! any idea

```
    public static void main(String [] arg) {
    int [] a=new int [64];
    for(int i=1;i<=a.length;i++){
        a[i]=i;
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: but when i change the for loop to for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) it works ,but i want it to be like above !!

Comment: You want to receive an exception? Elaborate what do you want to achieve and we will help you:)

Comment: In Java arrays start from index 0 and not 1, hence when your index will exceed 63, (becomes 64), the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Comment: If you need complete elaboration on why we get this exception, you can go through my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 15):

The array indexes in Java start from `0` and go to `array.length - 1`. So change the loop to `for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)`

Answer (score 3):

Indexes start from 0 so last index is 63. Change your for loop like this:
`for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){`

Answer (score 3):

See the [JLS-Arrays](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/arrays.doc.html):

> If an array
>   has n components, we say n is the
>   length of the array; the components of
>   the array are referenced using integer
>   indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive.

So you have to iterate through `[0,length()-1]`

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    a[i]=i+1;  //add +1, because you want the content to be 1..64
    System.out.println(a[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Need Complete Explanation? Read this

The index of an Array always starts from `0`. Therefore as you are having 64 elements in your array then their indexes will be from `0 to 63`. If you want to access the 64th element then you will have to do it by `a[63]`.

Now if we look at your code, then you have written your condition to be `for(int i=1;i<=a.length;i++)` here `a.length` will return you the actual length of the array which is 64.

**Two things** are happening here:

1. As you start the index from 1 i.e. `i=1` therefore you are skipping the very first element of your array which will be at the `0th` index.
2. In the last it is trying to access the `a[64]` element which will come out to be the `65th` element of the array. But your array contains only 64 elements. Thus you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The correct way to iterate an array with for loop would be:

`for(int i=0;i < a.length;i++)`

The index starting from 0 and going to `< array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java arrays always start at index 0. So if you want the last index of an array to be 64, the array has to be of size 64+1 = 65.

```
//                       start   length
int[] myArray = new int [1    +  64    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can correct your program this way :

```
int i = 0;     // Notice it starts from 0
while (i < a.length) {
    a[i]=i;
    System.out.println(i++);
}
```

Comment: I'd rather recommend to use the for-loop, because the loop index is only visible in the loop. In your case, `i` is also visible after the `while` loop.

Comment: @mklhmnn - Good point, but the main thing is `i` starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You've done your math wrong.  Arrays begin counting at 0.  E.g.  int[] d = new int[2] is an array with counts 0 and 1.

You must set your integer 'i' to a value of 0 rather than 1 for this to work correctly.  Because you start at 1, your for loop counts past the limits of the array, and gives you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.