# Java Array Exception Message

Tags: java, arrays, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420815/arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

How do I prevent the following message from showing:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at Test.main (Test.java:28 )

While compiling this code:

```
int [ ] a = { 2, 7, 8, 9, 11, 16 };  
for ( int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++ ) 
      System.out.println( a[i] ); // line 28 of class Test.java
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
for ( int i = 0; i <a.length; i++ ) 
  System.out.println( a[i] ); // line 28 of class Test.java
```

**Array indexes are zero based**. i.e., **Array indexes start from 0 to ArrayLength-1**

in your case to access the last index of an array, you have to do `a[a.length-1]`. thus your loop condition should be `i<a.length`

Answer (score 1):

The last index in your array is `a.length - 1` so, you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```